# Update gridview row add the old value and the new

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a `Gridview` and inside I have another one nested `GridView`. When I press a plus button the nested `GridView` expands using a `JavScript`. The nested `GridView` expands on edit mode using `TextBox` controls. So when the user types on a `TextBox` would have the ability to update the cell using an update button. My problem is that when I press the update button the update occurs but not how I would expected. If for example the initial value of a cell was “My name is Peter” and I have done the edit “I don’t have a name” The new value that will be saved is exactly this: “My name is Peter, I don’t have a name”. The databind of the nested `GridView` occurs on the parent `GridView` `DataBound` event. 
My code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="myitemID"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="../plus.png" />
                    <asp:GridView ID="nestedGridView"   runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        DataKeyNames="mynestedID">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="nestedID" Visible="false"  ItemStyle-Width="20%"
                                SortExpression="nesteditemID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="nesteditemID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nesteditemID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  ItemStyle-Width="20%"
                                SortExpression="Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="name" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="80%" Rows="3"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:Panel ID="mypanel" runat="server">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" OnClick="updatename_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/update.jpg" Width="15px" Height="15px" runat="server"></asp:ImageButton>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="myitemID" InsertVisible="False"
            SortExpression="myitemID" Visible="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="myitemID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("myitemID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ItemName"  ItemStyle-Width="20%"
            SortExpression="ItemName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="ItemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

cs code:

```
protected void updatename_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow masterrow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent.Parent;
    int index = row.RowIndex;
    int mi = masterrow.RowIndex;
    int i = index;
    GridView nestedGridView = (GridView)GridView1.Rows[mi].FindControl("nestedGridView");

    Label nestedID = (Label)nestedGridView.Rows[index].FindControl("nestedID");

    int sbid = Convert.ToInt32(nestedID.Text);
    TextBox name = (TextBox)nestedGridView.Rows[index].FindControl("name");
    string myname = Convert.ToString(name.Text);

    //update name with the new value
    Nesteditem updatenesteditem = mylinqobjects.Nesteditems.Single(p => p.nesteditemID == sbid);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myname))
    {
        updatenesteditem.nesteditemName = myname;
        mylinqobjects.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one? Because my problem is that the string that holds the value that will be inserted has both the old and the new value separated by comma

Comment: Yes but this code does not seems to be problem for me that's why asking about

Comment: No, if you put a red bullet on the last comment and check the string variable myname you will see that holds the old value and the new value saperated by a comma. I am stack 3 days on this issue. My query is just a linq statment that updates an object with this value

Comment: **myname** gives you old value + newer 1?

Comment: If for example the initial value of a cell was “My name is Peter” and I have done the edit “I don’t have a name” The  value that will be hold on the string myname is: “My name is Peter, I don’t have a name”.

Comment: Ya understood completely please put your whole code

Comment: ok i have update my post with the whole code

Comment: I found a post with a person had the same problem. http://forums.asp.net/t/1920580.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the current text by removing the old one.

```
string myname = name.Text.Substring(name.Text.LastIndexOf(",")+1);
```

Tried all possiblities, but due nested grid view rendering and its restrictions, we could do only like above.

Any others solutions, please provide.