# Javascript produces comma on every postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using this javascript to expand collapse nested gridviews.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "../plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```

The solution that i am using described exactly here:http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/135070/ASPNet-Nested-GridView-with-TextBoxes---Unwanted-comma-in-TextBox-after-PostBack/
My problem is that on every post back i am taking on the textboxes: "The old value" comma "The new value". It is  duplicating values .

Comment: This code doesn't seem to have anything to do with textboxes? It's changing the `src` attribute of some images.

Comment: No, this produces the problem There are many post that confirm that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: It must have to do with whatever `$(this).next().html()` is.

Comment: what does the html look like? where are the text boxes? the link you have provided has an answer... does that work for you?

Comment: No the above solution is not working for me. Inside i have a nested gridview. I am using the latest ajax toolkit but check also this:http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26259
also if you want to see my c# code you can check here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245851/update-gridview-row-add-the-old-value-and-the-new

Answer (score 0):

use 'on' instead of 'live' because live has been depreciated.

```
$("[src*=plus]").on("click", function () { // });
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, as clearly the OP is using an older version of jQuery that still has `live` or they'd have a very different problem to what they've described. When you have a rep of 50+ (won't take long!), you'll be able to comment. Until then, please just be patient rather than posting non-answer answers.